# Passing a reference to a class that inherits from a class that inherits from an interface

Tags: c#

What am I doing wrong with this code?

I have an interface, and a class that inherits this interface.

Then I have another class that inherits from that class.

When I try and pass this class as a parameter to a method that accepts a `List<that interface>` I get the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Scorer(ref System.Collections.Generic.List< ISearchResult>)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'ref System.Collections.Generic.List< ISearchResult>'

Here are my interface, class and method definitions, and the problem line of coded:

```
public interface ISearchResult
{
    double SearchScore { get; set; }
    string SearchIndex { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult : ISearchResult
{
    public double SearchScore { get; set; }
    public virtual string SearchIndex { get; set; }
}

public class MyData : SearchResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public override string SearchIndex { get; set; }
}

public void Scorer(ref List<ISearchResult> results)
{
    ...

...
List<MyData> myResults = q.ToList();
search.Scorer(ref myResults); //line with the errors
...
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used C# so this may have changed, but I don't believe lists are covariant. Can you make the interface consume an `IEnumerable<ISearchResult>` ?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, thank you, but just tried as IEnumerable and the error is the same.

Comment: Runs ok for me: https://gist.github.com/evantrimboli/b1d61b51e9a2724066cc375471c046c1

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, if I drop the `ref` it works with IEnumerable (but not with List), but I kind of need to pass by reference.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, the Scorer method iterates through the passed List and updates the value of one of the properties of each item in the List.

Comment: oooh, this seems to work: `public void Scorer<T>(ref List<T> results) where T : ISearchResult`

Comment: You don't need to pass it using `ref` to update the contents of the items: https://gist.github.com/evantrimboli/1e22eabd2d14b21d791be80dc291477d

Comment: Thanks @EvanTrimboli, I didn't realise that. It works without `ref` as IEnumerable (but not List).

Comment: Right, because if you could do something like that, the `Scorer` method could add any type of `ISearchResult` to the list you passed in. That has the potential to not be valid, so it's disallowed. Pretty sure that's why the covariance is only implemented on the "read only" types of things.

Comment: Makes sense. Did you want to add an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List<T>` type is not covariant, so you need to choose another type that is, for example `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.